# Difference between service and using alarm manager in android

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

In android a service is used to run in background. But the same can also be accomplished using alarm manager. The alarm receiver can do the same things that you would do in a service. So what is the need of service in android?

Answer (score 2):

Well Both are totally different thigns.

`AlarmManager` Class is used to perform certain Events on after specific Time Intervalr or it can be on a regular Time Interval. An Events can be execution of Service too. AlarmManager allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future.

While in case of `Service` it is a background process which doesnt have/requier a UI. A Service is not a saperate process or Service is not a thread. A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use

Comment: Even an alarm manager is a background process which does not require a UI. What ever you do in the service class, the same thing can also be done in the broadcastreceiver class.

Comment: well you can not schedule events in the Service class.

Comment: It depends on your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Actually these are two very different things. Alarm Manager can be used to do some tasks periodically using service. But Service can be used also e.g. to move some heavy work out of the UI thread(download data from rest server) or in case of foreground services, to do some work continously (mp3 player).

You can get some explanation on how to use service (with some advices considering AlarmManager) on [Styling Android](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/868).

Comment: You can set of the alarm immediately and in the onreceive() function do the heavy work in a seperate thread.

Comment: To be honest I never tried to do it this way. But Services are used for many other tasks without AlarmManager. For example I use a Service to download data from rest server and provide it to two different Activities. I want to be able to reach the same data and to reload the downloading from both of them. To be honest I can't think of a nice alternative to Service here. AlarmManager is completely useless in such task

Answer (score 1):

Generally,a service is used to process logic when you don't need a UI anymore. For example the service I want to use  checks a social networking site for updates every 15 minutes . The service has the logic of processing the update. But who will start the service every 15 minutes? That is where `AlarmManager` is used. It will periodically start my service every 15 minutes once, so that the service could execute its logic and stop itself once the job is done and my application doesn't keep draining the battery.

Comment: Exactly, that is what I am telling. "But who will start the service every 15 mins?". Why do you need to start the service every 15 mins. you can directly write the code for checking updates in the onReceiver() function of the broadcastreceiver.

Comment: I don't get what you are telling. Please explain in detail.

Comment: a broadcast receiver is fired when a matching intent is broadcasted. even IF an update is present in the social networking server, there could be no broadcasting of intent by the server in your mobile.It can be done from only within the mobile. A br is useless in this case. You can only find out about the update by making a connection to the server (from a service)

Comment: I will query my server in the broadcast receiver's onreceive() function. If there is a positive reply then I will push a notification. So what is the problem with this?

Comment: you can query the server in your br. but how you will start the br in the first place?